# Who can certify RNG according NIST SP800-22?

Tags: validation, certification, nist, random

I have written my own random number generator as a C library and I tested it on NIST Statistical Test Suite.

Now I would like to get a certification to have a formal proof that my C library generates random numbers randomly enough according SP800-22.

On a NIST web pages I'm not able to find some list of independent laboratory that could take my library, test it, and provide me certification.

Where can I find a list of companies/independent laboratories that can certify my RNG library according NIST SP800-22?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This certification is typically done through FIPS certification.

The list of labs certified by NIST to perform FIPS certifications is [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/testing_labs/)